# Parse iOS object duplication

Tags: ios, parse-platform

How to avoid that different users save the same string into the same column ? It would require to check in the specific column if the objects were already created...

Im not trying this for the PFUser class, to check duplicated users, its default.

Any code clue, start examples ?

Here follows my code that save the objects. The field _channelName is the one that can't be duplicated, that must be checked before saving.

```
- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {

// Create a new Post object and create relationship with PFUser
PFObject *newPost = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Channel"];
[newPost setObject:[_textView text] forKey:@"about"];
[newPost setObject:[_channelName text] forKey:@"name"];
[newPost setObject:[_enterKey text] forKey:@"enterkey"];
[newPost setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"owner"]; // One-to-Many relationship  created here!

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.channelImage.image, 0.8);

PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];
[newPost setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

// Set ACL permissions for added security
PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACL];
[postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:postACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
//PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[newPost setACL:postACL];


// Save new Post object in Parse
[newPost saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        // Dismiss the viewController upon success

    } else {

        //implement upload error message
    }
   }];

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Thanx and cheers!!!!

Comment: Can you post an example object? By default Parse creates a new object every time you instantiate and save an object unless you have queried or are specifically referencing something. A code sample would be a huge help in helping you :)

Comment: Yes, of course, no problem! As soon as I get near my project I'll post it in the question and reach you again.

Comment: Hey @RyanKreager I edited my question. Please  give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this this in two different ways. You can either use cloud code or you can do it client side.

Cloud code would look something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("YourClass", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("YourClass");
query.equalTo("uniqueColumn",request.object.get("uniqueColumn"));
query.first({
    success: function(object) {             
        if (object){            
            var currentUser = request.object;
            if (currentUser.id === object.id) { // if it already belongs to the user it's good
                response.success();
            } else { // otherwise it already exists and it belongs to someone else
                response.error("uniqueColumn exists");
            }
        } else { // If the object doesn't exist at all it's available
            response.success();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this uniqueColumn.");
    }
});     
});
```

You can do it client side by using the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method and checking to see if count on the returned array is greater than 0. So that would look something like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery ...];
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[_channelName text]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (objects.count > 0) {
        // Not unique, name already exist, handle it here
    } else {
        // Name is unique, proceed to save your object here

        // Create a new Post object and create relationship with PFUser
        PFObject *newPost = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Channel"];
        [newPost setObject:[_textView text] forKey:@"about"];
        [newPost setObject:[_channelName text] forKey:@"name"];
        [newPost setObject:[_enterKey text] forKey:@"enterkey"];
        [newPost setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"owner"]; // One-to-Many relationship  created here!

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.channelImage.image, 0.8);

        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];
        [newPost setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

        // Set ACL permissions for added security
        PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACL];
        [postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
        [PFACL setDefaultACL:postACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
        //PFACL *postACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
        [newPost setACL:postACL];

        [newPost saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                // Dismiss the viewController upon success

            } else {

                //implement upload error message
            }
           }];

          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}];

//...
```

Comment: Hi @SuperKevin thanks of r the reply. I think implement this in the client side would be better in my case. I posted in the question my current code that saves the objects to Parse. The field _channelName is the one that can't be  duplicated. In your client example above I should insert the PFQuery part ? Inside the successful condition right ? thnx and cheers!

Comment: I updated the code with your newly posted code, but I would recommend going the cloud code direction. It's much cleaner.

Comment: Wow Thanks mate! Hope it helps others too. The cloud code would have best performance/time ? Ḹess delay ? Using the cloud code would be necessary change any code in the client side too ? How to call that cloud in the client side ? Parse detects it automatically ?

Comment: If you are interested you can learn about it here https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide Good luck!

Comment: Great! I will check definitely! Cheers.